# Generate new Id based on generic TKey type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance

So, here is a bootstrap class library that I'm building:

```
class BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}

interface ICrudRepository<TItem, TKey> where TItem : BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    void Create(TItem item);
}

class MyCrudRepository<TItem, TKey> : ICrudRepository<TItem, TKey> where TItem : BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    IEnumerable<TItem> _items;

    void Create(TItem item) 
    {
        item.Id = GetNewId();
    }

    TKey GetNewId() 
    {
        // what should I do here?

        // with int, this would be 
        // return _items.Select(x => x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty().Max() + 1;
    }
}
```

My current BaseEntity doesn't have ae `TKey` parameter, instead it just uses and `INT` to store the item's key, but how could I extend it to support generics types as TKey? say `Guid`?
For example, how could I handle the generation of new items (see `GetNewId`)?
In case of a sequencial type, it should just use the existing collection and return the highest number, but on a `Guid`, ie, it should just generate another one

Here is the full code: https://gitlab.com/demedos/alexander.jsonorm

Comment: Your only option is to leave it as abstract and provide an implementation in a subclass, left as an excercise to the user. As an aside, providing your own keys (rather than, for instance, letting the DB create them with an auto-incrementing value) can only really work with GUIDs due to the virtually non-existent chance of collision with GUIDs generated by other clients. With the `key = oldKey + 1` mechanism, the moment you have more than one DB client, the scheme goes to s**t. Where possible, leave this to the database.

Comment: @spender I created this to quickly serialize and deserialize json items, the repo link is in the question. This made it impossible to generate ids outside the function

Comment: @spender And how could the client generate the Id if he doesn't know the collection size in case of and INT? Should the items count be exposed as a public property?

Comment: The client can't easily. As @spender said, if you want to generate keys on the client, use a GUID. Otherwise, you're asking for pain. If you absolutely must use an int, you should use an id that is unique to the request and replace it with a truly unique id that the server generates. Return that id as part of the response to the create request and the client then maps it back; this approach has gaps since there's a potential for things to go awry -- so either accept potential data loss/orphanage. The other option is to have the client reserve ids and then make the request. Or, use a GUID!

Comment: @spender Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. Now that I've thought about it, it makes sense to let the consumer generate the id, since that way custom consumer logic can be applied

Comment: @JasonArmstrong I don't really need to stick with Int, but I get the idea. It would still be a solution, but with all the drawbacks it comes with (data loss/unmatching keys)

Comment: @AlexanderD I feel perhaps a self-answer might be the best way forward. I'm not bothered by the rep thing.

Comment: @spender Me neither, just told in case. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the comments, the only solution is to let the consumer generate the ID based on its own logic and its BaseEntity type, so making `GetNewId` abstract does suffice.
Here is the relevant code

```
public class MyCrudRepository<TItem, TKey....etc
{
    [...]

    public abstract TKey GetNewId();
}
```